# Why is my App depended on .Net 8.0.2 and not .Net 8.0.0

Tags: asp.net, dependencies

I have an ASP .net 8.0.0 application (Web API) running as a Windows Service. With Inno Setup and "Inno Setup Dependency Installer", I try to make an installer that checks if the .net 8.0.0 is installed if not then download it and install it before installing my app.

But my app will not run on the server even when the .Net 8.0.0 is installed. But if I then install .Net 8.0.2 (the latest) it runs.

Why is my app dependent on .Net 8.0.2 when made with the VS .Net 8.0.0 template?
Is there a way to tell "Inno Setup Dependency Installer" that it downloads the latest of .Net 8.0?

Thanks in advance

Anders

Comment: Do you have a [mre]? In the build/publish folder check the `{AppName}.runtimeconfig.json` file (if there is one), what is set in the `frameworks` section?

Comment: Yes, the rintimeconfig.json says "name": "Microsoft.AspNetCore.App", "version": "8.0.0"
I have also checked the Nuget Packages but I don't see any depending on .Net 8.0.2

Comment: TBH I was not able to repro - app which was build with 8.0.2 SDK version runs just fine on machine which has only 8.0.0 runtime. It would be great if you would provide a [mre]. Also full error text and comand used to build/publish the app can be useful.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem with a small console or web API application. They both run with the .Net 8.0.
What can then be the problem?

Comment: Then you need to slowly add packages/stuff from your app to the repro until you will figure out what is causing the behavior. Maybe it is something in your build pipeline.

Comment: Removed "inno-setup" tag as it's not really relevant to this question.